# Subset function is not creating a subset of rows, but is instead changing values to zero

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe with both row names and column names.

```
    0.01    0.02    0.03   0.04   0.05 ...  Percent
J1   458    -160    -151    -52    -67        0.53
J2   459    -163    -154    -46    -92        0.01 
J3   457    -165    -150    -51   -245        0.27
J4   402    -297    -87     -93   -122        1.00
...
```

I would like to create a subset of data which would include only the rows for which the Percent column <= 0.5. 
The code for this seems rather straightforward...This is what I used:

```
C5.Subset<- subset(C5.Outliers, Percent<=0.5)
```

The output I am hoping for is this:

```
    0.01    0.02    0.03   0.04   0.05 ...  Percent
J2   459    -163    -154    -46    -92        0.01 
J3   457    -165    -150    -51   -245        0.27
...
```

However, the output I got is very different than expected.  Instead of creating a new table which excluded rows with a percent >0.5, R instead just replaced the value in the percent column to a zero for these rows.  This is the table I got for my results:

```
    0.01    0.02    0.03   0.04   0.05 ...  Percent
J1   458    -160    -151    -52    -67           0
J2   459    -163    -154    -46    -92        0.01 
J3   457    -165    -150    -51   -245        0.27
J4   402    -297    -87     -93   -122           0
...
```

I want to actually remove these rows.  What am I doing wrong?

FYI the code for this reproducible example works upon entering it.  My actual dataframe is from a CSV file with the same column and row names (dim=17x600).

Comment: Reproducible example please....?

Comment: WTF? you said it was a matrix! AND.... if that was brought in from a csv file with read.csv, those would NOT be the column names

Comment: So having tried your code and not gotten the wrong behavior, I'm inclined to close this as non-reproducible, unless you can provide an example that actually illustrates the supposed problem.

Comment: what @joran said.  Do you have a weird version of `subset()` masking the base version?  Results of (1) `find("subset")` (2) `sessionInfo()` please?

Comment: ... and try starting from a clean R session ... ?

Comment: Ok....having a lot of trouble explaining the issue.  I can't create a reproducible example when what I had originally was a .csv file, but provided the above code b/c you asked for something to input (will remove since it doesn't serve much purpose).  I am new to R, so still learning the differences between dataframes and matrices.  The table you see above is exactly what my .csv file looks like.  I got this table by transposing a table...before I did this column names were J1, J2, etc.  When transposed, R was fine with having #s at the top, but maybe R isn't recognizing these as column names?

Comment: @user507 You can create a reproducible example of the object you are working with by running `dput(head(C5.Outliers, 10))`. Then you can edit the output into your question like `C5.Outliers <- <output from dput>` so that we can reproduce the object. But before you do, *make sure your code actually reproduces the problem*

Comment: Also, thanks for everyone's patience as I am new both to R and to Stack.

Comment: Ok...have been unsuccessful trying to recreate this in a way which results in the same problem.  Will delete this question in a hour or so if I'm not able to do so.

Answer (score 1):

For the second version of the question, a tested response is just:

```
> subset( C5.Outliers, Percent < 0.5)
    X0.01 X0.02 X0.03 X0.04 X0.05 Percent
J 2   459  -163  -154   -46   -92    0.01
J 3   457  -165  -150   -51  -245    0.27
```

So like joran, I think you are continue to lie about what sort of object you are working with.

===== Answer to original question=========

My initial reaction was "subset is just for vectors and dataframes", but the manual says otherwise. However, if you look at the code (the ultimate authority on such matters) for `subset.matrix`, you see that the cute non-standard evaluation tricks in `subset.data.frame` are not present in the matrix-method. You need to create a proper expression that returns a logical vector as arguments to the subset-argument which is the row-oriented argument. There is some evaluation done on the arguments to select but you wanted a row selection process. Here's a matrix that matches yours and an example of 'subset'-ation

```
mat <- structure(c(458, 459, 457, 402, -160, -163, -165, -297, -151, 
-154, -150, -87, -52, -46, -51, -93, -67, -92, -245, -122, 0.53, 
0.01, 0.27, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(c("J1", "J2", 
"J3", "J4"), c("0.01", "0.02", "0.03", "0.04", "0.05", "Percent"
)))

> subset(mat, mat[,'Percent']< 0.5)
   0.01 0.02 0.03 0.04 0.05 Percent
J2  459 -163 -154  -46  -92    0.01
J3  457 -165 -150  -51 -245    0.27
```

Seems easier just to stick with using "[" for matrices.

Comment: Ok...I just edited my question above (should have written "data frame" rather than matrix.)  I have been working entirely with csv files and my row names include letters.  My understanding is that matrices are generally only comprised of numeric data? Therefore, if I have a csv file which includes letters, then I assume R would read it as a data frame?  If it's possible that R would be reading the file as a matrix, then the response you posted may indeed be my problem.

Comment: Matrices (in R) may be one of logical, character, numeric or list types. They may not have language elements, but that's about the only restriction on types. They are not allowed to have extra attributes, so they cannot contain dates or factors.

Comment: "lie" seems a little strong, it implies intent to mislead. "be confused"? "misrepresent"?

Comment: Just tried converting it to a data frame using data.frame(C5.Outliers) and I am still getting the same issue running the analysis afterward.

Comment: @BenBolker Yes. Saying it was a lie was probably too strong. I'll delete my accusation once the dust settles but at the moment what we really need is not some confused misrepresentation but rather the output from `dput( head( C5.Outliers))`

Comment: My guess is a weird version of `subset()` rather than a weird data object.